# Get a list of products with Tiered or special pricing

Tags: magento-1.9, database, sql

Recently updated pricing for the year and have had a couple issues with customers making transactions with last years lower tiered pricing. Is there a way to quickly detect which products have tiered pricing? So we can review them.

An SQL query would work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tier prices are stored in DB table: catalog_product_entity_tier_price

```
select DISTINCT (entity_id ) from catalog_product_entity_tier_price
```

The above query should give you all the product ids that have tier pricing setup.

Comment: thanks. just recently found the indexed pricing tables and they are quite helpful!